# Globalid and pg not existing when in gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

I am trying to rails server from a cloned repo, I have updated ruby, and rails, followed the rvm process, updated all my gem files, and when I go to serve I receive the message

> Could not find globalid-0.3.7 in any of the sources Run `bundle
>   install` to install missing gems.

So I do bundle install, then get the error

> An error occurred while installing pg (0.20.0), and Bundler cannot
>   continue. Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.20.0'` succeeds before
>   bundling.

Try to insall that and then get

> ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'globalid-0.3.7' (>= 0) in any 
>   repository ERROR:  Possible alternatives: globalid, globalize3

I have googled everything and asked many.

Comment: Can you post the `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`?

Answer (score 1):

globalid is a dependency of the Rails core gem ActiveJob so it is a required gem to have in your Gemfile.lock. See if it is listed in your Gemfile.lock file. If not you could add it to the top of your gemfile including the version

```
# gemfile
gem 'globalid', '0.3.7'
```

Then bundle install. If it works, then you can delete it from your gemfile since it should load automatically when Rails loads (since it is a dependency of Rails' ActiveJob). I've run into a similar issue with another gem and this process worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a version error. Try using gem 'globalid', '~> 0.4.0' in your gemfile and bundling.